# Eliminar filas que tienen todo 0(cero) en algunas columnas

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando eliminar unas filas de un data frame y se me esta complicando, por eso acudo en su ayuda.

Tengo un dataframe que tiene 15 columnas y 3975 filas. Lo que necesito es eliminar todas las filas que tengan valor 0 entre las columnas 8 y 15, ya que son las columnas que realmente tienen valores de ese estilo. De la columna 1 a la 7 los valores son para identificar a las variables y nunca alcanzan valor 0 por lo que no me "interesan" al armar el codigo. Adjunto dos imagenes con un ejemplo de lo que seria(no son las bases originales, sino una ilsutración).

Esto es lo que tengo :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdoa esta imagen, lo que me interesaria seria eliminar las fila las cuales tienen valor 0 en las columnas 2,3 y 4. El resultado final sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente seleccionando cada columna del dataframe mediante el operador "$"  y colocando !=0 para cada una de las columnas las cuales quiero que contemple, pero no me estaria funcionando.
Tambien intente utiliar lapply con la funcion(z), y la función subset. En ambos casos me sucede que la tabla permanece sin cambios, con la misma cantidad de registros.

Espero haber sido claro, desde ya muchas gracias!

PD: Estaría bueno poder seleccionar las columnas mediante su numeración, ya que al ser varias, es un poco tedioso escribir el nombre de cada una de ellas.

Comment: Saludos @nico, también debes adjuntar a tu pregunta lo que has tratado o investigado, por favor lee [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;)

Comment: @Israel-ICM perfecto, ya edite y agregue lo que estuve intentando realizar. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imaginando un `data.frame` como el siguiente:

```
set.seed(2021)
df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol= 10))
df

   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
2   1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0
3   1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   0
4   1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
5   0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
6   1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
7   1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
8   1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
9   1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
10  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0   1
```

Si quisiéramos eliminar aquellas filas dónde solo hay 0, por ejemplo, en las columnas 6 a 9, podríamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
df[!apply(df[,6:9] == 0, 1, all), ]

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  0   1
3  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1   0
4  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0   1
5  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0   1
6  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   1
7  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   0
8  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1   0
9  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1   1
```

Y hemos conseguido eliminar la fila 2 y la 10. La idea es:

1. `df[,6:9] == 0` nos da una matriz de lógicos, dónde `TRUE` nos indica que hay un 0.
2. `apply(df[,6:9] == 0, 1, all),` aplicamos a la matriz por fila, la función `all`, el resultado serán, un vector de lógicos dónde `TRUE` serán las filas dónde todas las columnas mencionadas sean 0.
3. Por último, simplemente negamos la selección anterior de filas par recuperar justamente las filas de interés.

Comment: Muchas gracias!